# Does maven have a way to modify the version number according to the specified situation?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I want to use maven to package according to some situations, such as the first case with the 1.0 version of the b package, the second case with the 1.1 version of the b package

I have used the <profile> tag, and found that when the package is referenced The version number of the displayed b package is not the version number in the <profile> tag, but the version number in the external <properties> tag.

```
 <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <hadoop.verison>2.6.0</hadoop.verison>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>tdh602</id>
        <properties>
            <hadoop.verison>2.7.2-transwarp-6.0.2</hadoop.verison>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>cdh514</id>
        <properties>
            <hadoop.verison>2.6.0-cdh5.14.2</hadoop.verison>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
        <version>${hadoop.verison}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I use command:
    mvn clean install -DskipTests -Ptdh602 
Then I found that the version number of hadoop-common is 2.6.0 instead of 2.7.2-transwarp-6.0.2 in another project which used this packaged jar

Answer (score 0):

I think your version specific dependencies should be part of profile.

```
   <profile>
        <id>tdh602</id>
        <properties>
            <hadoop.version>2.7.2-transwarp-6.0.2</hadoop.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-common</artifactId>
                    <version>${hadoop.version}</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    </profile>
```